# How do I define a type based on the query projection

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way of defining some generic dynamic type in TypeScript, that would allow me to define the type based on the projection parameters?

Say, you want to execute a database query, or you're executing a GraphQL request.
You're gonna have a function like

```
interface Person {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

function getPeople(projection: (keyof Person)[]): Promise<Partial<Person>[]> {...}
```

I mean, if I now execute `getPeople(['id', 'firstName'])`, then the returned objects will never have any property `lastName` since the projection was configured to never load that into memory. Is there any way I could indicate this on the type level, rather than simply using `Partial<Person>` that still allows me to reference uninitialized properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue here is that we need to make `getPeople` generic, in such a way that we can reference the type of the parameters in the return type. This should do what you want to achieve:

```
interface Person {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

type Fields<P, keys extends keyof P> = {
  [key in keys]: P[key];
};

declare function getPeople<keys extends keyof Person>(
  projection: keys[]
): Promise<Array<Fields<Person, keys>>>;
```

Comment: TypeScript can be that way sometimes. I find that it helps to ask yourself "how do I describe the output in terms of the input", create a type (in our case `Fields`) that does this, and then introduce a type parameter in our generic function that calls the type we previously created.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this

```js
function getPeople<K extends keyof Person>(projection: K[]):
Promise<Pick<Person, K>[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface EntityType {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

const EntityObject: EntityType = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };

function EntityProjection<T extends keyof EntityType>(projection?: Array<T>): Pick<EntityType, T> {
  return EntityObject;
}

function useIt() {
  const x = EntityProjection(['a']);
  
  x.b // will throw error
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make properties to optional. Use `?` key to make it optional.

```
 interface Person {
      id: string;
      firstName?: string;
      lastName?: string;
    }

   function getPeople(projection: (keyof Person)[]): Promise<Partial<Person>[]> 
   {...}
```

Now except id, all the properties are optional.

Comment: this is great, but it's not what I was aiming for.
I want this call -`(await getPeople(['id']))[0].firstName` - to give me a compiler error saying "'firstName' does not exist on type X"

Comment: Define return type like this `function getPeople(projection: (keyof Person)[]): Promise<Person[]> 
   {...}`

Try this I hope it will work

Comment: well... this works in general, but in this case when I call `person.lastName` the whole thing compiles nicely and I get a  value `undefined`, whereas I would like it to become impossible to compile to JS in the first place, long before I run it, if I ever reference the property lastName. This is not going to be the case with the solution you're proposing